# Accessing Desktop through Android device

Tags: android

Is there any way of accessing, editing,deleting files on the desktop through your android Device??

Is it possible through Socket Connection?? I dont like to go for Internet connection (remote access).

Comment: Do you mean the desktop of some computer? How would you do that without Internet?

Comment: logically,but not sure you must need internet connection.

Comment: ok.. if we use Internet, how do we do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But for that, you will need a desktop client as well. If you don't want a GUI based app, you could look at ConnectBot. It works over ssh though.

Answer (score 2):

Real VNC can do the job. Try to search it in the android market.

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer it is free. http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx
It use port 80. To implement your I would suggest the same architecture as they are using